# "How the clustal omega can be reverse engineered, to trace ancestral inversion mutations via the guide tree?"

Tags: phylogenetics, genomics

I apologise for very basic question but I am very new to biology and have very specific knowledge of this field, I am currently working on Bioinformatics in my machine learning project which is why I need to be sure about obtained results before I proceed. I am not aware of all the tools used in genomics/bioinformatics. I would like to know that what tools can be used if I want to trace and observe the strand orientations in the ancestral inversion mutations? I would like to know the key concepts as well, using which I can automate the process in my program and display the orientation.

Comment: Hi @Pragati I dunno its difficult to understand your project. Could you define your question, e.g. organism, distrubution. What are is your training sett ... input and output?

Comment: The question you are asking can be done via phylogeny, HOWEVER your project is to use ML, DNN instead of phylogeny. Personally, I wouldn't fancy taking on the question, because in my view there is too much we don't know. It is just my opinion however.

Comment: Completely agree that this sounds like a phylogeny project. For a software to find genomic rearrangements (inversions and the like), you can check out Mauve: http://darlinglab.org/mauve/user-guide/introduction.html . But you'll need to break up your project into questions that you can actually tackle, and acquire a lot of domain knowledge.

Comment: @Michael I need to analyse the inversion mutations: Any tool to do this directly will be useful. Thanks for your suggestion I will look into details.

Comment: @csgroen I agree that I will have to acquire more knowledge if I am tackling tricky bits of the project. I'll check out the software. Thank you

Comment: "inversion mutations" I dunno, I do genetic mechanisms but I don't really understand the term. Is this a reference to a locus, or some sort of compensatory mutation? If it is a inverted locus, is it a reference to the "inversion" as being the mutation?